# projection differences in R

Tags: r, coordinate-system

I am trying to reproject some climate data that I downloaded from http://gdo-dcp.ucllnl.org/downscaled_cmip_projections/dcpInterface.html#Welcomein

The BCSD-CMIP5 data is found under the tab "Projections: Complete Archives".

The files are in netCDF format, but am running into some issues.  The original raster data (let's call it rast1)  when imported has the extent

```
xmin 235.25
xmax 293
ymin 25.125
ymax 52.875
```

and a crs of +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0

The other objects (both sp and raster) I am working with contain negative values for xmin and xmax

```
xmin        : -122.8021 
xmax        : -75.38249 
ymin        : 31.78881 
ymax        : 47.15952
```

When I try to reproject rast1 using the other objects (rast2), the extent does not change and even though the reprojected rast1 is in the same crs, the extents don't line up.

```
rast_new = projectRaster(rast1, rast2)
```

So I had to do the following:

```
rast_new = projectExtent(rast1,rast2)
rast_new = projectRaster(rast1,rast_new)
values(rast_new) = values(rast1) ### This is necessary because all the values were NA
```

However, even though rast_new is in the same projection as rast2

```
+proj=aea +lat_1=20 +lat_2=60 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83
+units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80+towgs84=0,0,0
```

the plotting isn't the same. See image [image: plots of two images with same crs]

Just wondering what I can do to correct this? Needless to say, I am relatively new to understanding projections in R ( and projections in general!)

I have exported the two rasters and viewed in ArcGIS, to see if it was a plot() issue in R, but the images are the same as above, yet the projections are the same (according to ArcGIS 10.2). Even when I reproject the "bad" raster in ArcGIS, the projection does not appear to be in Albers Equal Area. When I import directly from the netCDF file into ArcGIS, the projection looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the first image is using the WSG84 geodetic reference system, whereas the second image is using [GRS80](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRS_80), which is why is looks curved. This suggests the objects haven't been converted to the same CRS.

Can you provide the climate data, or a sample, so I or another user can look into this further?

Comment: I added some additional information to the question.

Comment: Please can you link directly to the relevant files. I don't know which item on the website is `rast1`, `rast2`, etc.

Comment: rast1 would be one of the netcdf files in the archive (e.g. ftp://gdo-dcp.ucllnl.org/pub/dcp/archive/cmip5/bcsd/BCSD/access1-0/rcp45/mon/r1i1p1/pr/ It doesn't matter which one, all have the same extent and projection. rast2 is simply a spatial object in another projection. In my case albers equal area.

Comment: I tried to obtain an appropriate file for `rast1`, but I'm not hunting around. If you can provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), with explicit links to objects `rast1`, `rast2`, etc. I can try to recreate the issue and suggest a solution. As it stands, I can't help you further.

Answer (score 1):

I posted at R-SIG-GEO and got this response from Dr. Hijmans.

http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/Raster-projection-alignment-issues-td7587564.html

Basically, you need to manually adjust the extent of the raster object. Specifically,

```
extent(r) <- extent(235.25-360, 293-360, 25.125, 52.875),
```

or use the rotate function from the raster package